# Initialize Spring batch DB before application bean is created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm trying to create a bean like so:

```
@Bean
public Clock clock(JobExplorer explorer, Environment environment) {
   // Check last run time of job and create a Clock bean
}
```

But when the application starts up, I get the error: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` because the spring batch schema hasn't been created by spring boot's `BatchAutoConfiguration` yet.

Then, I tried to do this:

```
 @Bean
 @ConditionOnBean(BatchDatabaseInitializer.class)
 public Clock clock(JobExplorer explorer, Environment environment) {
   // Check last run time of job and create a Clock bean
 }
```

This shifted the error from when clock bean was created to when a bean requiring `Clock` was created:

```
@Bean(name = "reader")
public ItemReader<Record> itemReader(
              JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, Clock clock) {
     // Create item reader
}
```

`Error: No qualifying bean of type [java.time.Clock] found for dependency`

This keeps cascading. If I put a `@ConditionalOnBean` on `itemReader` method, then when a bean that requires `itemReader` is created, I get the same "No qualifying bean" error.

So, How do I make sure that spring batch schema is initialized before my beans are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to use `@DependsOn()` annotation? I was not aware of ConditionOnBean..

Comment: Yup. That worked. The `ConditionOnBean(YourBean.class)` is part of spring-boot project. I'd misunderstood it's usage.